# JDBC fastload - OutOfMemory after 20 million addBatch() operations

Tags: jdbc, teradata, out-of-memory

I am using Teradata jdbc driver 13.00.00.10, and trying to upload a flat file with 100 million rows to teradata.

I start off with a clean table.

First I tried to iterate through the entire file, do addBatch() for each of the rows, and only in the end do a single executeBatch():

```
        while ((s = reader.readLine())!=null ){
            String[] columns = StringUtils.split(s, separator);
            for (int j=0; j <columns.length; j++){
                st.setString(j+1,columns[j]);
            }
            st.addBatch();
            i++;
            if (i % 10000 ==0 ){
                ULogger.info(this, "imported " + i + " lines.");
            }

        }
        st.executeBatch();
```

This quickly consumes all the memory for my application.

I set the 9GB XMX, and got OutOfMemory after ~40 million addBatch().

Then I tried to do periodic executeBatch() - iterate throgh the file and every 20 million addBatch() do an executeBatch().

```
       while ((s = reader.readLine())!=null ){
            String[] columns = StringUtils.split(s, separator);
            for (int j=0; j <columns.length; j++){
                st.setString(j+1,columns[j]);
            }
            st.addBatch();
            i++;
            if (i % 20000000 ==0 ){
                   st.executeBatch();

                   st.clearWarnings();
            }

        }
        st.executeBatch();
```

In this case, the first executeBatch() succeeded.

However, The second executeBatch() failed, with "errror while beginning FastLoad of database table XXX".

Can anyone explain how I'm supposed to load 100 million rows?

Is there a configuration I am missing (e.g. to tell the driver to push some updates periodically and not hold them in memory)?

Thanks,

A.

Comment: What does your statement look like?

Comment: It appears there is an answer to your question on Teradata's Developer Exchange. If the solution there was correct could you please update this question here. (I hate loose ends...) :)

Answer (score 2):

Got an answer on the Teradata user forum, which directed me to the FAQ - (http://developer.teradata.com/connectivity/faq) where it says that the right way to work is by calling executeBatch() periodically; 
however, in order to do that, you need to first turn off autocommit on the connection, 
and make sure to commit in the end.

so my code looks like this now:

```
        **con.setAutoCommit(false);**
        while ((s = reader.readLine())!=null ){
            String[] columns = StringUtils.split(s, separator);
            for (int j=0; j <columns.length; j++){
                st.setString(j+1,columns[j]);
            }
            st.addBatch();
            i++;
            if (i % 20000000 ==0 ){
                   st.executeBatch();

                   st.clearWarnings();
            }

        }
        st.executeBatch();
        **con.commit();**
```

works like a charm.

The only thing which is not 100% clear from the FAQ is what should be the chunk size.
it says something confusing like "as large as your JVM heap can sustain" and also "in future we will recommend to set it to be 50K-100K. These two seem to contradict each other, I've set it to 10 million and it's working find.

Also - there is apparently a CSV fastloader feature in Teradata JDBC - see http://developer.teradata.com/doc/connectivity/jdbc/ reference/current/jdbcug_chapter_2.html#BABFGFA2 -which may give better performance in general.